# How to make a simple resume

Tags: resume

I like the sytle of [this resume](http://www.pranavmistry.com/files/pranav_cv.pdf)

It is simple and clear. But it is made by Word.

How to write a tex version?
[image: resume.pdf]

Comment: to eliminate cv monotony for employers use a `LaTeX-made` as per your taste/style. See [ctan here](http://www.ctan.org/topic/cv) and [moderncv tag](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderncv). It's a good occasion to add `LaTeX` in your skills set. if you find a duplicate of your question in the tag list, paste here

Comment: Another place where to look for CV examples is [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae)

Comment: I'd use a list environment, e.g. as provided by the package `paralist`. You'll need to adapt the left margin, look for `\setdefaultleftmargin{2em}{}{}{}{.5em}{.5em}` in the manual.